# Does an angular acceleration applied to a large body affect any bodies orbiting it?

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, thought-experiment

Imagine the Earth (large body) and a single satellite, let's exclude all other bodies for this example. The satellite is orbiting the Earth parallel to the equator and is maintaining a constant distance from the center of the Earth. No energy is being added to the satellite. Relative to the orbiting satellite, the Earth has a constant angular velocity.

Now imagine that an angular acceleration is applied to the Earth in the direction which the satellite is orbiting. The angular acceleration starts at some number and approaches 0 so that the Earth is now stationary with respect to the orbiting satellite.

Does the satellite's orbital path change in this instance?

Comment: Yes, see; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging#Effects